# what is synchronization of thread in java?

Tags: java

what is synchronization of thread in java?
give any example on it in detail

Comment: Search on Google and you'll find lots of great examples.

Comment: This looks like homework. Please find out the basics by yourself and then ask some more specific questions about it here.

Comment: I don't typically answer homework questions in detail. But an answer copy/pasted from here is as good as an answer copy/pasted from any other website. It isn't as though there is a programming question here.

Answer (score 1):

In multi-threaded programs there are often sections of the program that need to be run atomically (as if it were a single operation). These are generally referred to as critical regions and are protected using mutual exclusion (mutex) paradigms. The `synchronized` keyword in Java is one such way of providing mutual exclusion.

Consider the code:

```
synchronized(lockObject) {
  //critical code
}
```

In the above code, only one thread may enter that synchronized block at a time so long as the object reference by the variable `lockObject` is never changed. This ensures that the code executed within the synchronized block is only ever executed by a single thread.

Common examples of where locking is needed would be when iterating over a collection. Few Java Collection implementations offer thread safe iteration. A basic way of creating thread safe iteration would be to protect every access to the collection with a synchronized block on that collection.

For example:

```
synchronized(myCollection) {
  myCollection.add(item);
}

synchronized(myCollection) {
  myCollection.remove(item);
}

synchronized(myCollection) {
  for(Object item:myCollection){
     System.out.println(item);
  }
}
```